# Notify changes in the database

Tags: database, jsp, servlets, notifications

Here is a snippet of the script I am using to fetch record in the database.

```
   var url = '../waitOrders?restaurant_id=1;

    $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
            setInterval(function() {$("#displayarea").load(url); }, 400);
        });
```

It works fine but my question is that is there a way to notify me that the database has a new record or changes?

Answer (score 1):

1) You can write the triggers for that, which is informed you whenever new entry of data is occure.

**OR**

2) you can use User Define Functions which helped you when new entry comes to database.

Comment: do you have any examples of triggers?

Comment: sorry, buddy i don't have.
but you can find on google

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what database you are using but if you were using php and mysql:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `articles`.`title`  FROM `articles` LIMIT 6");

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['title'], '<br>';
}

echo '<p>Returned ', $query->rowCount(), ' results</p>';
```

the $query object is using the rowCount() method to return the number of records added to the databases, so not sure if this answers your question.